# MySQL select query ranking list with condition

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following query to create a ranking list:

```
 SELECT Count(a2.performance) rank, 
       a1.performance, 
       a1.wind, 
       a1.name, 
       a1.surname, 
       a1.dob, 
       a1.prov, 
       a1.pos, 
       a1.place, 
       a1.date 
FROM   men a1, 
       men a2 
WHERE  a1.performance > a2.performance 
        OR ( a1.performance = a2.performance 
             AND a1.name = a2.name 
             AND a1.surname = a2.surname 
             AND a1.wind = a2.wind 
             AND a1.dob = a2.dob 
             AND a1.prov = a2.prov 
             AND a1.pos = a2.pos 
             AND a1.place = a2.place 
             AND a1.date = a2.date 
             AND a1.event = '100m' 
             AND a1.year = '2016' ) 
GROUP  BY a1.name, 
          a1.surname, 
          a1.performance 
ORDER  BY `a1`.`performance` ASC
```

My table looks like this:

```
| id | event | performance | wind | name | surname | dob | prov | pos | place | date | year |
```

My ranking list works perfectly, but I would also like to add a condition to the `event` and `year` fields, which is not part of the output. Where I have the `year` and `event` condition it does nothing. Anyone that could help so that it filters by those to fields please.

This is what the table looks like:

```
|id|event|performance|wind|name|surname|dob|prov|pos|place|date|year|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1|100m |   10.00   |2.0 |John|  Coe  |   |    |   |     |    |2016|
| 2|100m |   10.01   |2.0 |John| Smith |   |    |   |     |    |2017|
| 3|200m |   20.10   |2.0 |  U |  Bolt |   |    |   |     |    |2016|
| 4|100m |   10.05   |2.0 |Pete|  Doe  |   |    |   |     |    |2016|
```

This is what I am getting:

```
|rank|performance|wind|name|surname|dob|prov|pos|place|date|
| 1  |   10.00   |2.0 |John|  Coe  |   |    |   |     |    |
| 2  |   10.01   |2.0 |John| Smith |   |    |   |     |    |
| 3  |   10.05   |2.0 |Pete|  Doe  |   |    |   |     |    |
| 4  |   20.10   |2.0 |  U |  Bolt |   |    |   |     |    |
```

This is what I want where the conditions is event=100m and event=2016 and it ranks everything that gets outputted.

```
|rank|performance|wind|name|surname|dob|prov|pos|place|date|
| 1  |   10.00   |2.0 |John|  Coe  |   |    |   |     |    |
| 2  |   10.05   |2.0 |Pete|  Doe  |   |    |   |     |    |
```

Comment: question isnt clear

Comment: What type of condition you're after if the `year` and `event` are present?

Comment: which datatype is year ??

Comment: year is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'like' instead of '='

Also, I would double check the syntax on the 'OR'..it looks like everything after the or would be disregarded if a1.performance > a2.performance

Answer (score 0):

I found this and adapted it and it does the trick:

```
SELECT rank, performance, wind,name,surname,dob,prov,pos,place,date FROM
(SELECT performance, wind,name,surname,dob,prov,pos,place,date,
@curRank := IF(@prevRank = performance, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank, 
@incRank := @incRank + 1, 
@prevRank := performance
FROM Men p, (
SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1
) r 
WHERE year='2017' AND event='100m' 
ORDER BY performance) s
```